# Deduct from file until value is less than or equal to 20

Tags: bash

I was just looking for a bit of guidance for this, as I'm kind of stuck right now and have been repeatedly doing the same thing. The "blah.txt" file would be the positional parameter and then I want to keep deducting values of "20" from it until it is less than or equal to 20. I also have to use a positional parameter for the filename...

```
 #!/bin/bash

 value=$(cat "blah.txt")


 if [ "$value" -ge 20 ]

 then

    until [ "$value" -le 20 ]; do
            echo $((value - 20)) > $1

    done

 fi
```

Comment: `/bin/sh` is POSIX sh (on systems where it's compliant with early-90s standards), not `bash`. (On systems following 1970s-era conventions, it would be Bourne shell, which is even *more* not bash). If you're using a `#!/bin/sh` shebang, then the `bash` tag is incorrect.

Comment: You are right - I corrected the shebang as I meant to use bash, my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `value="100"`. Then you can use it in arithmetic expressions as follows:

```
until [ $value -le 20 ]; do
  echo $value
  (( value -= 20 ))
done
```

*Output*

```
100
80
60
40
```

If you want to exclude `100` from the list, move arithmetic expression to the loop condition, e.g.:

```
until (( (value -= 20) <= 20 )); do
  echo $value
done
```

*Output*

```
80
60
40
```

If you want to include `20`, then replace `-le` (lesser or equal) with `-lt` (lesser), and `<=` with `<`.

Comment: It works with the second example, but then it only subtracts to 40. Any idea which part causes that?

Comment: @v2kv, it depends on what you want to achieve. For `value=100`, the first loop iterates through `{100, 80, 60, 40}`; the second - through `{80, 60, 40}`. If you want to include `20`, then replace `-le` with `-lt`, and `<=` with `<`.

Comment: Yeah, I managed to play around with it and figured that part out. I think my main issue was the way I used echo with the arithmetic expression, in my example. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, you just echo `$value - 20`, but never actually store that. Basically let's assume the value is 100 at the beginning. Then you keep writing 100-20 = 80 on the screen, but never actually decrement the value of the variable.

Comment: I should note that $value would display a numeric value contained in "blah.txt" (say, something like 200 or 300, it doesn't matter). I then use "$value -20" to subtract 20 from the value in "blah.txt", and then store the new value with $1, where "blah.txt" is the argument. It actually does subtract from the value, in that case, but the issue is it will only do it once...so if the value was 60 it becomes 40 and that's it. Then it just hangs in execution.